# Adding custom type formatting, with all the usual options

Tags: c++, fmt

I've made a Decimal class and want to use the fmt library.
I read that the way to define a type to the formatter is to specialize `fmt::formatter`.
But, there is no information in the docs on how to call into the existing common infrastructure.  The formatting codes for field alignment and overall width and fill character, for example: that should be common code that works across any type.
How do I write a formatter specialization without re-implementing the entire specification from scratch?

I'd like to start by making my type compatible with the floating-point formatting specifiers, so when a type is changed from `double` to decimal it will continue to work the same; but then add additional features specific to the type.

```
template <int S, int F>
struct fmt::formatter<Decimal<S,F>> {

constexpr auto parse(format_parse_context& ctx) {
    [[maybe_unused]] auto it = ctx.begin(), end = ctx.end();
    // dummy stub.  just take the whole thing
    it = std::find(ctx.begin(),end, '}');
    return it;
}

template <typename FormatContext>
auto format(const Dec& x, FormatContext& ctx) {
    constexpr size_t bufsize = 64;
    char buf[bufsize];
    const auto end = x.to_chars (buf, buf+bufsize, false);
    const std::string_view sv { buf, size_t(end-buf) };
    return std::copy(sv.begin(),sv.end(),ctx.out());
}
};
```

Comment: The way I read the example and documentation is that you should just output the full data, and let the formatting library worry about field widths, justifications and other such things.

Comment: No, trying `{:^*30}` with my custom type doesn't do anything.  It prints exactly what I fed the output iterator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

{fmt} doesn't yet provide facilities for parsing standard format specifiers. Internally it uses [`fmt::detail::parse_format_specs`](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/73c8437485bf13e92b525e1f107fee2c5d7375c3/include/fmt/format.h#L2496). It needs to be cleaned up a bit and moved to the public API for reuse.

Comment: Any update on this a year later? I notice it's now called `fmt::<ver>::detail::parse_format_specs`—so, still private. Is there a recommended way to use it, or to accomplish this by another, supported, means? (Thanks)

Comment: The main change is that parsing is now consistent with C++20 std::format and better works with Unicode but it's not part of the public API yet.

Comment: No public updates yet, have been busy with more important stuff such as compile-time checks. But it is on our radar: https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/issues/2086.